# Creating a RESTful Web Service with Java and Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat

I'm trying to test a simple web service, starting with the **GET** method using **Tomcat 7**, under Netbeans I created a Web Application, added Tomcat server, added **Jersey libraries** and went for the guided "Create RESTful Web Services from Patters" option.

I set the relative path to a custom wanted, however, everytime I try to access to that path, lets say `http://localhost:8080/TestingREST/webresources/service` I'm getting the following message:

> HTTP Status 404 - /TestingREST/webresources/service
>
> type Status report
>
> message /TestingREST/webresources/service
>
> description The requested resource (/TestingREST/webresources/service) is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

Looking for help I read I should change something in a ***web.xml*** file but such file is not beign generated in my project...

Comment: Please include the code of your class extending `Application` and the signature of the class and method with the `@Path("/service").

Comment: Refer this link for creating restful service http://vichargrave.com/restful-web-service-development-with-netbeans-and-tomcat-tutorial/